# How do create an outer border thicker than the cell borders in a table?

Tags: html-table, css-tables

I have some tables, and I want the four outer borders of these tables to be thicker than the borders dividing the individual cells. Other than manually changing the border thickness on each and every cell that happens to border the outside (which is not efficient at all), how do I do this?

Another thing I might like to try is, while I have all borders collapsed right now, I may want these outer borders not to be collapsed (instead of thickened). But I don't know how to pull that off either.

Complicating matters is the fact that I only want to do this with a few of the tables on my document. There are a whole bunch I have on my document overall--and most of those I want to all have the 1px thickness all around. But there are a few special tables that I want with a 3px outer thickness. So how do I do this in CSS without messing up the other tables?

Anywhere, here is a sample table whose outer border I want to thicken:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th colspan="2">Quest Complete</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Legend of the Sage</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Nopon Sage<br/><br/>Ask a child in Frontier Village to tell you why the<br/>Nopon Sage is so great.<br/><br/><br/>You understand a little better why the<br/>Nopon Sage is so great.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:165px">4500 G<br/>1500 EXP<br/><br/></td>
<td style="width:165px">Poison Plus V<br/>Revival HP Up III<br/><br/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

(Yes, this is a video game thing. =P)

And here's what I have for my CSS stylesheet:

```
table {width: 360px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f0f0f0}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica; line-height: 1.25}
th, td {padding: 3px}
```

Comment: With collapsed borders, a thicker border always takes priority over a thinner one, so had you simply tried to declare a border on the table element, it would have just worked. BTW, it is unnecessary to double up all those styles on both table and cell. The font styles will be inherited if they are simply declared on the `table`.

Answer (score 1):

It overwrites the CSS, adjust as per priority.
In your scenario, you can change CSS to this,

```
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica; line-height: 1.25}
th, td {padding: 3px}
table {width: 360px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f0f0f0;border: 10px solid black;}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Savan! This worked (esp. once I figured out how to set up a 2nd CSS style). But I'm thinking about going with a separated border instead of a thickened one. How do I make it so the outer border is separated but the cell borders remain collapsed? Is that possible?

Comment: You can apply border types such as solid, groove, dotted etc. [check this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp)
If you want to set outer border use div tag in parent of table.

Comment: [Refer this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_test)
Just change CSS to
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
table {border: 5px solid black;}

In addition to that you may use border-right, border-left etc.

Comment: It was unnecessary to change the order of selectors. With collapsed borders, a thicker border always takes priority over a thinner one.